# Remove default close ( X ) button from ant design Notification

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using Notification component from ant design and I want to remove close (X) button from Notification box.

I've tried adding `closable: false` and `icon: null` but not working

```
notification.info({
    description: "Sample description",
    closable: false,
    icon: null 
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ant Design Notification doesn't accept `closable` prop. Please read the [documentation](https://ant.design/components/notification/).

Comment: Correct. Ant design notification is built using `rc-notification` which accepts closable property, but unfortunately Ant design doesn't.

Comment: I somehow hacked it by adding `className` and making `ant-notification-notice-close`'s `display` property to `none`  

`.className .ant-notification-notice-close {
    display: none;
}`

Answer (score 5):

if you are using Ant Design >= 3.x notification have a property call closeIcon which accepts ReactNode you can use `closeIcon : (<div></div>)` to hide the close icon. check the doc here [Notification Component](https://3x.ant.design/components/notification/)

> Happy Coding...

Comment: It can also be done with Fragment: 
closeIcon : <></>